# Python 2.7 mock a void method of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I am trying to use `unittests.mock` to mock a void method call of an object.

My package is like below

```
common
  baseupgradehandler.py
```

**baseupgradehandler.py**

```
class BaseUpgradeHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, upgrade_config, upgrade_state, system_config, pre_step, main_step, post_step):
        ...

    # Method call to be supressed
    def start(self, service_manifest, upgrade_bundle):
        # type: (service_version_pb2.ServiceManifest, str) -> ()
        ...
```

In my test code I am trying to mock the call to `start()` like below as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-classes).

```
from workflow.upgradeworkflow import UpgradeWorkflow
from common.serviceregistry import ServiceRegistry
# The above imports are at the start of the test file
...
with patch('common.baseupgradehandler.BaseUpgradeHandler') as handler_mock:  # type: Mock
    handler_mock.return_value.start.return_value = ''                    
    wf = UpgradeWorkflow(ServiceRegistry(self.service_bundle, config, sys_config, state),
                         config,
                         state,
                         sys_config)
```

`BaseUpgradeHandler` object is returned by `get_upgrade_handler()` method of `ServiceRegistry`. When I am executing the above code in test I am seeing the `BaseUpgradeHandler.start()` is still getting called.

Can someone let me know how can I mock the call to a `start()` so that the method is not called?

**EDIT**

If I change my patching code like below it is working as expected and `BaseUpgradeHandler` is getting mocked and `start` is not getting called.

```
with patch('common.baseupgradehandler.BaseUpgradeHandler') as handler_mock:  # type: Mock
    handler_mock.return_value.start.return_value = ''
    with patch('common.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry') as serviceregistry_mock:  # type: Mock
        serviceregistry_mock.return_value.get_upgrade_handler.return_value = handler_mock
        wf = UpgradeWorkflow(ServiceRegistry(self.service_bundle, config, sys_config, state), config, state, sys_config)
        wf.start()
```

Can someone explain me why do I have to patch `ServiceRegistry` as well?

Comment: `patch` used as a context manager only patches the method inside the `with` block. You are probably calling it outside. If you want to patch that method for a whole test method use `patch` as a decorator. Also: you can mock just the method if you want to `patch('mcommon.baseupgradehandler.BaseUpgradeHandler.start') as method: method.return_value = ''`

Comment: @Bakuriu -  No I am not calling it outside. I have edited the question. I don't want to patch the whole test method. So I have used `with`. If I follow your suggestion and make `patch('mcommon.baseupgradehandler.BaseUpgradeHandler.start') as method: method.return_value = ''` then this is working as expected. I have multiple methods to mock in `BaseUpgradeHandler`. So do I have to mock each of the methods as you have suggested or there is some other way?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. How are you checking that the real method is being called? We will need a **complete** example that reproduces the issue to understand why patch isn't working in your case. Maybe you are accessing that class via a reference taken before the patching. If you put `patch` as decorator does the behaviour still occurs?

Comment: @Bakuriu - I have edited my question. It is a part of bigger code base. I will try to have a complete toy example. But do let me know if the above edit provides any clue.

Comment: Just a tip: it does not matter that you come from a huge code base. Start by "commenting out" all the code not used by that test. Then comment out all the classes/functions/methods not directly used by that single test. Then change implementations of functions that lookup files/database to just return a fixed result. Now it does not matter where you came from you should have very very few classes with almost no implementation in them. See if the problem is still there. If not try to add a bit more code and repeat. Most of the time  with this process you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is not enough to see the part that causes the issue. We'd need to see the module `serviceregistry` to be sure but I'd take an educated guess:

You have a file `a.py` (aka `baseupgradehandler`) like this:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print("It's real!")
```

And a file `b.py` (aka `serviceregistry`) like this:

```
from a import A

class B:
    def get_A(self):
        return A()
```

In your test files you do this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from b import B
from a import A
```

**GAME OVER!**

The `B` module right now has already got its reference to the original `A` class. When, **afterwards**, you `patch('a.A')` **only** the reference in the `a` module is changed, but `patch` has no way to know that `B` has its own reference to the original `A`.

You can fix this in three ways:

- patch the method: this will modify the existing class so all references to that class will be automatically patched
- patch `b.A` too:

  ```
  with patch('a.A') as h_a, patch('b.A') as h_b:
      h_a.return_value.method.return_value = ''
      h_b.return_value.method.return_value = ''
  ```
- Avoid importing the modules before patching (probably not feasible or a good idea):

  ```
  import unittest
  from unittest.mock import patch

  class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_one(self):
          with patch('a.A') as h:
              h.return_value.method.return_value = ''
              from b import B
              B().get_A().method()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using unittest.mocks for a while, and I have been re-inventing the wheel sometimes. I decided to make mockito part of my project and now things look way better. Any kind of mock verification is really simple, if you can, I definitively encourage you to make mockito part of your libraries. This library has a good documentation and so far it has been easier than unittest.mock IMHO.